# How to Make 3dsMax Object from Transparent Picture (.png)?

Tags: png, 3dsmax

Let's say I create a transparent image (without background) via Photoshop from the geometry I draw, and saved it as "png" file. I would like to shape 3dsMax object, i. e. plane according the geometry of my drawing from "png", and then extrude it in the case to have 3D object (but not necessary, only shaped plane can be enough for some projects). How to shape 3dsMax plane following the path of the image in "png"? Is there any converters?

Comment: It could be a brilliant idea to make 3D logo.

Comment: You have to draw or trace the image using shape **Paths** in Photoshop. You then save that as vector format like **.AI** or **.EPS**  (using "Export paths" option or similar).. in 3DS Max you'll import the [path's] EPS or AI file (they look and work like splines) for **Extruding**. Been a while since I did it but that's the process. **AI** is Adobe Illustrator format so its all about vectors imported into 3DS Max.. Google around to double check anything (supports newer vector formats like SVG? etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically, after the modifications via Photoshop I opened "jpg" file in Adobe Illustrator (it is possible to open .psd files directly), and made a path there:

1. Object>Image Trace>Make
2. Object>Image Trace>Expand
3. Delete picture frame anchor points.
4. Choose Colors (right panel), Swap Fill and Stroke (left panel).

Then I saved as .ai file (Illustrator 8 version is fine for 3dsMax 2009), finally, imported into 3dsMax (File>Import...), and have their that shape.

Comment: Source: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/modeling/3d-object-from-transparent-png/td-p/4395493